# Openshift v3: after starting the SpringBoot / Mysql application the app is killed after a few secs

Tags: openshift

After building the app, the deployment process works. The SpringBoot (mysql) application is deployed and marked as the usual "Starting the application".

After a few seconds, there is a message saying it "kills" the application. Notice, I am just within the limits of my Openshift free quota.

What is the mesage?  .../wildfly/bin/standalone.sh: line 307: 183 Killed "java" -D"[Standalone]"
**See the line in bold.**

On another time I see is that the application is started, I can even login, but then after a minute is is killed.

> 14:47:15,334 INFO  [nl.xyz.Application] (ServerService Thread Pool --
>   66) Started Application in 26.49 seconds (JVM running for 57.227)
>   14:47:15,723 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config]
>   (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.13.SP1
>   20160303-1204 for context '' **/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh**: **line 307: 183
>   Killed "java" -D"[Standalone]"** -server -XX:+UseParallelGC -Xms40m
>   -Xmx250m -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.LOW_MEMORY=true -DOPENSHIFT_APP_UUID= -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djboss.node.name=solvedcaches-5-80fj7 -Djgroups.bind_addr=0.0.0.0 -Dorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION=on "-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log"
>   "-Dlogging.configuration=file:/wildfly/standalone/configuration/logging.properties"
>   -jar "/wildfly/jboss-modules.jar" -mp "/wildfly/provided_modules:/wildfly/modules" org.jboss.as.standalone
>   -Djboss.home.dir="/wildfly" -Djboss.server.base.dir="/wildfly/standalone" '-b' '0.0.0.0' '-bmanagement' '0.0.0.0'

The last 2 build failed due to a generic build failture. Strange, the code was hardly changed. It looks like rebuilding takes memory and is competing with the running application and vice versa. The last time I stopped the POD, then deployment was ok.

Comment: Please look for the kill reason. I think it is Kubernetes, which kills the application, because it uses more memory than permitted. So check the restart reason with `oc describe <pod>`. You may also give more memory just to test. A second problem could be a health check, which checks too early and kills the applicaiton -> but this would also be visible in the events (Openshift Online Web Console -> Monitoring -> Monitoring and Events)

Comment: I reduced the app as far as possible. I see in the follow-log that the build finishes with Success. When I look into the monitor I see build failed "generic build failure ran for 55s". With "oc get pods" I see that it is "OOMKilled". So I even cannot do a "oc describe ...". What can I do? The app is already "skin and bones". Can I change the memory settings?

Comment: You can adjust the memory limit for the app in the *Deployment Configuration*, if the default limit (`oc describe limits resource-limits`) is not sufficient. However as you indicated you're just within the limits of your quota (OpenShift Online free Starter plan), you will need to reduce the memory limit for your MySQL deployment config first. The build process is using [terminating resources quota](https://www.openshift.com/pricing/index.html), and is limited to the same 512 MiB per container by default, if not specified otherwise in the *Build Configuration*.

Comment: @Jiri Fiala, please put your comment as answer. 
After playing the memory settings of both PODs the application gets more stable. Can you please suggest what is a good memory resource setting for MySql? Then I can give the application more space and stability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you **@Jiri Fialka** for all your help, online / offline. 
As you suggested, after configuring the memory over the 2 POD's the application is working fine. Now I use 410 Mb for Mysql and 600 Mb for SpringBoot was WAR on a Wildfly pod. Even SSH was added within minutes!. 
I am enthusiastic about the new Openshift v3 facilities. Also the GUI and oc.